# mapping soap request from source to target using dozer

Tags: java, deep-copy, dozer, docusignapi

I am creating a wrapper around an external service, docusign.
I am trying to use dozer to map my wrapper service objects to docusign objects. I am trying to do a deep copy.

I have tried to keep both the source and target names in most cases - but dozer doesn't copy beyond the first level.
In the below example i have - after conversion, i see that the compositeTemplates node was never copied from source to target. May be because - it has a list inside?! i dont know.

My dozer mapping is:

> ```
> <mapping map-null="false">
>     <class-a>com.foo.wrapper.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms</class-a>
>     <class-b>com.foo.docusign.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms</class-b>
> </mapping>
> ```

I then tried specify the field name in the mapping file - but i get null pointer exception. Any pointers on this is appreciated.

> ```
> <mapping map-null="false">
>     <class-a>com.foo.wrapper.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms</class-a>
>     <class-b>com.foo.docusign.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms</class-b>
>     <field>
>     <a>ArrayOfCompositeTemplate</a>
>         <b>CompositeTemplate</b>
> </field>
> ```

Source:

> ```
> <doc:initiateESign>
>      <InitiateEsignProcessRequest>
>         <doc:createEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms>
>            <doc:envelopeInformation>
>               <doc:subject></doc:subject>
>            </doc:envelopeInformation>
>            <doc:compositeTemplates>
>               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
>               <doc:ArrayOfCompositeTemplate>
>                  <doc:inlineTemplates>
>                     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
>                     <doc:inlineTemplate>
>                        <doc:envelope>
>                           <doc:transactionID></doc:transactionID>
>                           <doc:asynchronous></doc:asynchronous>
>                           <doc:recipients>
>                              <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
>                              <doc:recipient>
>                                 <doc:id></doc:id>
>                              </doc:recipient>
>                           </doc:recipients>
>                        </doc:envelope>
>                     </doc:inlineTemplate>
>                  </doc:inlineTemplates>
>                  <doc:document>
>                     <doc:name></doc:name>
>                  </doc:document>
>               </doc:ArrayOfCompositeTemplate>
>            </doc:compositeTemplates>
>            <doc:activateEnvelope></doc:activateEnvelope>
>         </doc:createEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms>
>      </InitiateEsignProcessRequest>
>   </doc:initiateESign>
> ```

Target:

> ```
> <ns:CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms>
>      <ns:EnvelopeInformation>
>         <ns:Subject></ns:Subject>
>      </ns:EnvelopeInformation>
>      <ns:CompositeTemplates>
>         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
>         <ns:CompositeTemplate>
>            <ns:InlineTemplates>
>               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
>               <ns:InlineTemplate>
>                  <ns:Envelope>
>                     <ns:TransactionID></ns:TransactionID>
>                     <ns:Recipients>
>                        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
>                        <ns:Recipient>
>                           <ns:ID></ns:ID>
>                        </ns:Recipient>
>                     </ns:Recipients>
>                  </ns:Envelope>
>               </ns:InlineTemplate>
>            </ns:InlineTemplates>
>            <ns:Document>
>               <ns:Name></ns:Name>
>            </ns:Document>
>         </ns:CompositeTemplate>
>      </ns:CompositeTemplates>
>      <ns:ActivateEnvelope></ns:ActivateEnvelope>
>   </ns:CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms>
> ```

Any pointer on how to map these two via dozer would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I know DocuSign's APIs pretty well but have never used dozer, I think you'll need help from people who are knowledgable with dozer for this.

However doing a visual scan of what you've posted one thing I wanted to take a stab at.  I see in the source you've listed the order of the compositeTemplate elements as

```
<doc:compositeTemplates>
          <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
          <doc:ArrayOfCompositeTemplate>
```

But in your dozer map you have

```
<mapping map-null="false">
<class-a>com.foo.wrapper.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms</class-a>
<class-b>com.foo.docusign.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms</class-b>
<field>
<a>ArrayOfCompositeTemplate</a>
    <b>CompositeTemplate</b>
```

In your map you have the order of CompositeTemplate vs ArrayOfCompositeTemplate reversed.  Could that possibly be the cause of your issue?